# Derivative of double integral with respect to symmetric limits in square roots

Tags: integration, derivatives

Can anyone help me to get the following integral?

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} \int_{-x}^x f(y,z) \;dy\; dz$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $$F(x,\;z)=\int\limits_{-x}^x f(y,z) \;dy.$$
Then, by using [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), we have 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} F(x,\;z) dz=\dfrac{F(x,\;\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{F(x,\;-\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}+\int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} \dfrac{\partial{F(x,\;z)}}{\partial{x}} dz\\
=\dfrac{F(x,\;\sqrt{x})+F(x,\;-\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}+\int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} {\left(f(x,z)+f(-x,z) \right)} dz.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle{\large{{\rm d} \over {\rm d}x}\int_{-\sqrt{x\,}}^{\sqrt{x,}}\int_{-x}^{x}
{\rm f}\left(y,z\right)\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z:\ ?}$

> $$
> \int_{-x}^{x}{\rm f}\left(y,z\right)\,{\rm d}y
> =
> {\rm sgn}\left(x\right)\int_{0}^{\left\vert x\right\vert}
> \sum_{\sigma = \pm}{\rm f}\left(\sigma\,y,z\right)\,{\rm d}y
> $$

> \begin{align}
> \int_{-\sqrt{x\,}}^{\sqrt{x\,}}\int_{-x}^{x}{\rm f}\left(y,z\right)
> \,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z
> &=
> \sum_{\sigma,\sigma' = \pm}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x\,}}
> {\rm sgn}\left(x\right)\int_{0}^{\left\vert x\right\vert}
> {\rm f}\left(\sigma\,y,\sigma'z\right)\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z
> \\[3mm]&=
> \sum_{\sigma,\sigma' = \pm}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm sgn}\left(x\right)
> \Theta\left(\left\vert x\right\vert - y\right)
> \Theta\left(\sqrt{x\,} - z\right)
> {\rm f}\left(\sigma\,y,\sigma'z\right)\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z
> \end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &{\partial\left[{\rm sgn}\left(x\right)
> \Theta\left(\left\vert x\right\vert - y\right)
> \Theta\left(\sqrt{x\,} - z\right)\right] \over \partial x}
> \\[3mm]&=
> 2\delta\left(x\right)
> \Theta\left(\left\vert x\right\vert - y\right)
> \Theta\left(\sqrt{x\,} - z\right)
> +
> {\rm sgn}\left(x\right)
> \delta\left(\left\vert x\right\vert - y\right){\rm sgn}\left(x\right)
> \Theta\left(\sqrt{x\,} - z\right)
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{}+
> {\rm sgn}\left(x\right)
> \Theta\left(\left\vert x\right\vert - y\right)
> \delta\left(\sqrt{x\,} - z\right)\,{1 \over 2\,\sqrt{x\,}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> 2\delta\left(x\right)\Theta\left(-y\right)\Theta\left(-z\right)
> +
> \delta\left(x - y\right)\Theta\left(y\right)\Theta\left(\sqrt{x\,} - z\right)
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{}+
> {\rm sgn}\left(x\right)
> \Theta\left(\left\vert x\right\vert - y\right)
> \delta\left(\sqrt{x\,} - z\right)\,{1 \over 2\,\sqrt{x\,}}
> \end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &{{\rm d} \over {\rm d}x}\int_{-\sqrt{x\,}}^{\sqrt{x,}}\int_{-x}^{x}
> {\rm f}\left(y,z\right)\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z
> =
> \sum_{\sigma,\sigma' = \pm}
> \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x\,}}{\rm f}\left(\sigma\,x,\sigma'z\right)\,{\rm d}z
> +
> {1 \over 2\,\sqrt{x\,}}\sum_{\sigma,\sigma' = \pm}\int_{0}^{\left\vert x\right\vert}
> {\rm f}\left(\sigma\,y,\sigma'\sqrt{x\,}\right)\,{\rm d}y
> \end{align}